# referencing to an index dataframe and retrieving data where matches occur

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and keen to learn but am finding myself particularly stuck on what seems to be a relatively straightforward idea.

I have 2 dataframes. The first (ants) is data pertaining to a number of sites, each site has a unique ID, some sites have more than one row of data.
It look like this:

```
 Site           Date          Time          Temp 
71             8-Jun-10       14:50:35       14.32  
71             8-Jun-10       14:51:29       14.31  
70             8-Jun-10       14:53:55       14.3      
70             8-Jun-10       14:54:09       14.3     
70             8-Jun-10       14:54:24       14.3      
69             8-Jun-10       14:56:30       14.28
```

The second (HRsites) is an index of the latitudes and longitudes associated with each site number.

```
Site    lat_52           long_00 
69      56.3075            9.1957 
70      56.4207            8.9147 
71      56.5208            8.6265
```

What I would like to do is...Where the site numbers of the two dataframes match, I would like the corresponding lat and long data held in 'HRsites' to be added under additional new columns in the 'ants' dataframe.

I see that a new column is added by 
    ants$lat_52<-

...and this is where I'm stuck, I'm not sure of the huge range of functions available on R and feel I'm perhaps not searching using quite the correct language. Any help would be hugely appreciated....even if it's jus the terms of functions I should be searching for.

Comment: As an aside, it's helpful if you provide us with some test data with dput(head(your_df, 20))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to `merge` them by "Site".

```
> lines <- "Site Date Time Temp
+ 71 8-Jun-10 14:50:35 14.32
+ 71 8-Jun-10 14:51:29 14.31
+ 70 8-Jun-10 14:53:55 14.3
+ 70 8-Jun-10 14:54:09 14.3
+ 70 8-Jun-10 14:54:24 14.3
+ 69 8-Jun-10 14:56:30 14.28"
> 
> (ants <- read.table(con <- textConnection(lines),header=TRUE)); close(con)
  Site     Date     Time  Temp
1   71 8-Jun-10 14:50:35 14.32
2   71 8-Jun-10 14:51:29 14.31
3   70 8-Jun-10 14:53:55 14.30
4   70 8-Jun-10 14:54:09 14.30
5   70 8-Jun-10 14:54:24 14.30
6   69 8-Jun-10 14:56:30 14.28
> 
> lines <- "Site lat_52 long_00
+ 69 56.3075 9.1957
+ 70 56.4207 8.9147
+ 71 56.5208 8.6265"
> 
> (HRsites <- read.table(con <- textConnection(lines),header=TRUE)); close(con)
  Site  lat_52 long_00
1   69 56.3075  9.1957
2   70 56.4207  8.9147
3   71 56.5208  8.6265
> 
> (Data <- merge(ants,HRsites,by="Site"))
  Site     Date     Time  Temp  lat_52 long_00
1   69 8-Jun-10 14:56:30 14.28 56.3075  9.1957
2   70 8-Jun-10 14:53:55 14.30 56.4207  8.9147
3   70 8-Jun-10 14:54:09 14.30 56.4207  8.9147
4   70 8-Jun-10 14:54:24 14.30 56.4207  8.9147
5   71 8-Jun-10 14:50:35 14.32 56.5208  8.6265
6   71 8-Jun-10 14:51:29 14.31 56.5208  8.6265
```

Comment: Many thanks Joshua! Now I have learnt the MERGE function :) One query I have is that when I perform this, everything's perfect except that the decimal places of some my lat long data are reduced to 0 or just 1 decimal place from 5 or even 6 decimal places. I've been trying to format the affected columns specifying number of decimal places desired...any ideas why this could be?

Comment: `merge` does not alter the data.  Either you're doing something before or after merging that is dropping precision, or it could just be how the data are displayed.  If you're missing precision when you write the data to a text file, then the former case is your issue.

Comment: Sorted...yes it was just how the data are displayed. Sorry, thanks!